# With padding 0px, why does a button display differently in Edge than in Blazor Webview?

Tags: css, blazor-hybrid

I would like to make a button that has the same look in Edge than in Blazor Webview.
I have set the following css for the buttons.

```
button{
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 0px;
font-size: 1rem;
font-family:Arial;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;}
```

Here is what I get in Edge
[image]
And here in Webview
[image]

Why is the vertical padding not the same?